# apache bin rpm from source

Tags: apache-2.2

I have apache source(1.3.x) and I have configured and installed it. Now I need to build a binary rpm with the compiled version that I have so that it can be installed in multiple other machines. The OS and environment I will be installing these will be constant. I understand I need to build a spec file but I am not sure how and what I need to know to build it.

I am just thinking if make install command can be used in some way to get my spec file, or the list of files I need to install, and modifications I need to do to some confs.

The apache 2.0.46, seem to have a spec file along, but for 1.3.x I do not see one.

oh yeha, I do not have the option to move to 2.2.x now, so I have to work with 1.3.x for some time.

Answer (score 1):

- you can try with [CheckInstall](http://asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall/). From the homepage:

> When make install is done, CheckInstall will create a Slackware, RPM or Debian compatible package

- you can look in the archives of an old RedHat (if I remember correctly 4) release which had apache 1.3.x and take the spec file as a start point
- you can take the spec file of the 2.2.x version and adapt it

Comment: That should work. It's important to note, you should _carefully_ inspect the `.spec` file CheckInstall produces. It takes a large number of arguments, and has very generic defaults for them.